# SWFobject inside iFrame: Cross domain stuff?

Tags: iframe, flash, embed, swfobject

I have a simple html-site with an embedded Flash file and SWFobject is used on it.

This site is the src of an iframe. If I open the site with the iframe on it the console tells me …

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///experiment/iframe-
test/index.html from frame with URL http://localhost.lan/embed/GYZA. Domains,
protocols and ports must match. -> swfobject.js
```

I wonder what the parent window (with the iframe in it) has to do with the swfobjet inside the iframe? So as mentioned above the swfobject is used to embed the flash on the child-page that is loaded into the iframe. The `iframe-test/index.html` site has just …

```
<body>
    <iframe src="http://localhost.lan/embed/GYZA" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
```

… on it. Nothing more. Why do I have an `unsafe javascript attempt here`?

Any ideas on that? Thank you in advance.

**update:** Well, I just recognized that this happens to Youtube and Vimeo as well for their embedded players. I'm using the chrome console and the same error occurs for Youtube and Vimeo.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is of any use now but the error is thrown because `file:///experiment/iframe-test/index.html` and `http://localhost.lan/embed/GYZA` are seen by the browser as two different domains so the browser's cross domain policy deems this unsafe. Depending on the browser the user has, this might be unsafe - the remote page you are loading could have harmful scripts that might destabilize the current page you are viewing or try and steal various pieces of information. You can find more info [here](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes).

Answer (score 0):

I just validated Matt's updated question.

Whenever a flash object is embedded in a cross-domain iframe, it will throw a cross-domain exception. This is true for Youtube and Vimeo.

For example, check out this jsfiddle with an iFrame embedded: http://jsfiddle.net/bkCdB/

```
<object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/6V_DsL1x1uY?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/6V_DsL1x1uY?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```